# conflicting types for Function’ struct error in C

Tags: c, struct, parameter-passing

I currently am trying to pass a struct to a different file using a header file. It also gives me the warning "struct Connection’ declared inside parameter list". Three are three files, piggy1.h,piggg1.c, and ear.c. Any thoughts on why I can't get this code to compile?
Thanks so much guys!

```
//piggy1.h----------------------------------------
void ear(struct Connection *connect1);

//-------------------------------------------------*
//ear.c --------------------------------------------
include "piggy1.h"

void ear(struct Connection *connect1){}

//---------------------------------------------------*
//piggy1.c -------------------------------------------

include "piggy1.h"


struct Connection{
int llport;
int rrport;
char rraddr[50];
int noleft;
int noright;
};

 main(argc, argv)

int argc;
char *argv[];
{
int cases;
int noright = -1;
int noleft = -1;
int rraddr = -1;
int llport = -1;
int rrport = -1;
struct Connection connect;
}
```

Comment: This is an ancient syntax. Where does this code come from?

Comment: Help from a old school professor

Answer (score 1):

I defined the struct into the header file and this solved the problem! Place the following code into the header file.

```
struct Connection{

   int llport;
   int rrport;
   char rraddr[50];
   int noleft;
   int noright;
};
```

Comment: It would be sufficient to place `struct Connection;` in the header before the function declaration.    You should not be writing K&R-style code; you should only use prototypes.

Comment: Can you explain this a little more? Are you saying to code using 1TBS style? What is a prototype?

Comment: What is a prototype?  `void ear(struct Connection *connect1);` is a prototype declaration of a function; `void ear(struct Connection *connect1){ … }` is a prototype definition of a function.  A prototype lists the type of the variable as well as its name inside the parentheses of the function argument list, in contrast to non-prototype definitions such as `main(argc, argv)

int argc;
char *argv[];` which is archaic and not a prototype.  That should be `int main(int argc, char **argv)` (or `char *argv[]`), with an explicit return type.  That is the non-prototype (K&R) function notation.

Comment: I'm not referring to style (1TBS vs Allman, etc — I use Allman, but you seem to use 1TBS; both are valid choices).  I'm referring to an 'opaque type' or an 'incomplete type'.  Your header file could contain two lines: (1) `struct Connection;` — which says "there is a type called `struct Connection` but the compiler doesn't need any more details yet; and (2) `void ear(struct Connection *connect1);` — which says "there is a function `ear` that takes a pointer to a `struct Connection` and returns no value".

Comment: With the original header, the type `struct Connection *` is only known in the prototype (it has 'prototype scope'), and that is practically useless (and theoretically not much different from useless).  In fact, compilers normally complain when they encounter a new type in a prototype because it is useless.  The extra line declares the type outside the function prototype and makes everything work once more.

Answer (score 0):

Conflicting error means the parameters passes in your definition section and parameters passed in your declaration section do not match.

In your case, the error is shown because definition and declaration of ear function is done before the struct definition.

The compiler doesn't recognise your parameters and so an error is thrown.